# List containing Managed Metadata when exported to Excel has weird characters?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata, export-to-excel, taxonomy

I have a calendar All Events list which contains few fields, some from Managed Metadata and People presence lookup fields. When I try to use the Ribbon feature to export the list into an Excel, each of the field values have an id hash tag along with it.

This makes the excel sheet very much useless and unreadable.

Has anyone tried or come across this issue in SharePoint 2010 platform and how to export the data into an Excel without the id # tags.

For instance:
Attended by: field contains the list of Users with people presence enabled.
When I export this field value into Excel, then each User gets copied into the sheet with their own unique # tag as in Doe, John;#39 
Or if it's a Taxonomy Managed Metadata lookup field, then the export data will have their unique # tag in front of the value as in 74;#Ford

Please let me know if you can help. Do ask me freely if you have any questions or need further clarifications.

One suggestion was to try to copy the value into a calculated field as simple text replacing the # tags. But I cannot create columns based off calculation from existing lookup fields. 
Other suggestion is to create a macro in Excel workbook Book1, which can be coded to remove these hash tags.

I am hoping that there is some other simpler way to clean up the Excel data sheet.  Please let me know. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Answer here is create a cleanup macro in Excel that is then accessible to all spreadsheets via an .xlam addin that is stored in the XLSTART local machine directory.

This VBA code isn't pretty, but it works like a charm:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
Sub Remove_unneeded()

' Remove_unneeded Macro
' Removes extraneous hash setup from SharePoint exported workbook

Dim Again As Integer
Dim Again1 As Range

On Error GoTo Nope

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="?;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
If Again1 Is Nothing Then
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#?", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Again1 Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Nope
    End If
End If

Range("A1").Select
Again = 1

Do While Again < 5
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="0;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="0;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="0;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="1;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="1;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="1;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="2;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="2;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="2;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="3;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="3;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="3;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="4;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="4;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="4;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="5;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="5;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="5;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="6;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="6;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="6;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="7;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="7;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="7;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="8;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="8;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="8;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="9;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:="9;#", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="9;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#0", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#0", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#0", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#1", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#1", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#1", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#2", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#2", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#2", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#3", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#3", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#3", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#4", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#4", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#4", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#5", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#5", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#5", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#6", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#6", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#6", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#7", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#7", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#7", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#8", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#8", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#8", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop

    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#9", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
        Cells.Replace What:=";#9", Replacement:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#9", LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop
    Again = Again + 1
Loop

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Replace What:="#;#", Replacement:=" | ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#;#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Replace What:=";#", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:=";#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#;", LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Replace What:="#;", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#;", LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="#", LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop

Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="; |", LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not Again1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Replace What:="; |", Replacement:=" |", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Set Again1 = Cells.Find(What:="; |", LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop

Range("A1").Select
MsgBox "Extraneous hash data has been deleted."
Exit Sub

Nope:
    MsgBox "This is not the proper spreadsheet setup to run this macro."

End Sub
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I also created an additional macro in the xlam with an iRibbon control to access this macro via a button on a custom ribbon in Excel and then edited the xlam UI xml to accomodate that.  But that's window dressing as you can set up the UI any way you like once you have the macro ready to use.

You do have to turn on "Trust VBA Project Object Model" in Excel Options in the Trust Center, Macro Options.  Unless of course you have the ability to digitally sign the addin.

Comment: Excellent, this is more like a real user solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I have this page bookmarked and visit it quite often as I regularly export data from SharePoint to excel. Thanks a bunch (and upped)!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this issue was to create a new column in the list, name it as you wish on my case was "OnlyValues". I created a Workflow so that whenever an item was created or updated on the list I proceed to update "OnlyValues" with the value of the "Person Group" field for example

---

```
Person or Group field = AssignedTo
Auxiliary field = OnlyValues
```

---

```
Workflow:
If Current Item:AssignedTo is not empty
 Set OnlyValues to Current Item:AssignedTo
then Stop the workflow and log Success
```

---

After that I created a view on the list showing my other fields and OnlyValues and exported to excel. Hashtags are now gone! Hope this helps anyone! ^^

Answer (score 0):

I too, used an macro to clean it up

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Columns to format
    Dim cols() As Variant: cols = Array("AC", "AL", "AM", "BA", "BB")
    Dim col As String


    For i = LBound(cols) To UBound(cols)
        Call FormatColumn("Sheet1", cols(i))
    Next

    MsgBox ("Formatting Lookup & Person - Group column completed.")
End Sub

Sub FormatColumn(ByVal Shet As String, ByVal col As String)
    Dim flagValueChanged As Boolean: flagValueChanged = False
    Dim strPattern1 As String: strPattern1 = "#\d+;"
    Dim strPattern2 As String: strPattern2 = "#\d+"
    Dim strPattern3 As String: strPattern3 = "#"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    'process for all items in the column

    rowscount = Sheets(Shet).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    'i = 16
    For i = 2 To rowscount
        flagValueChanged = False
        currentValue = Sheets(Shet).Cells(i, col)
        'MsgBox (currentValue)

        'format Pattern1
        With regex
           .Pattern = strPattern1
        End With

        If regex.Test(currentValue) Then
           currentValue = regex.Replace(currentValue, strReplace)
           flagValueChanged = True
           'MsgBox (currentValue)
        End If

        'format Pattern2
        With regex
           .Pattern = strPattern2
        End With

        If regex.Test(currentValue) Then
           currentValue = regex.Replace(currentValue, strReplace)
           flagValueChanged = True
           'MsgBox (currentValue)
        End If

        'format Pattern3
        With regex
           .Pattern = strPattern3
        End With

        If regex.Test(currentValue) Then
           currentValue = regex.Replace(currentValue, strReplace)
           flagValueChanged = True
           'MsgBox (currentValue)
        End If

        'update formatted value
        If flagValueChanged Then
           Sheets(Shet).Cells(i, col) = currentValue
        End If

        'MsgBox (currentValue)
    Next i

End Sub
```